# Breeze property validation using data annotations in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations, breeze

Within my entity framework model I have:

```
<Required(), Range(0, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage:="Weight must be numeric and cannot be negative")> _
Public Property Weight() As Double

<Required(), Range(0, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage:="Recycled content must be numeric and between 0 and 100")> _
Public Property RecycledContent() As Double
```

And in my viewmodel I have:

```
        if (!editComponent().entityAspect.validateProperty("recycledContent")) {
            /* do something about errors */
            var msg = 'Recycled content is invalid!';
            logger.logError(msg, error, system.getModuleId(lt_articleEdit), true);
        }
```

And yet when I enter a value greater than 100 (in the recycled content field) it still passes validation somehow!  I have used the script debugger to step through and in the breeze validation routine there are two validators registered which are "required" and "number" but nothing that I can see mentions the range.

Can breeze do range validation?  All I'm trying to do is pick up a data validation error based on metadata from the data annotations of the model and use this to trigger a client-side highlight on the field in error and log an error message.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very reasonable request but we aren't quite there yet.

Right now Breeze doesn't YET pick up Range validations from Entity Framework metadata. Please vote for this on the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3899620-support-net-validation-attributes) .  This matters because we do prioritize our work based on this venue.